# Android adb stop working

Tags: android

Until yesterday everything was working perfect until today that I connected my phone (just updated to Jelly Bean) and adb.exe stop working. If I execute adb.exe I can see the help but when I want to use any command it just run forever and no message is shown.

I tried with "kill-server" and "devices" and it runs forever, no message at all is displayed and I must terminate the process to close it.

I just connect the same phone to other PC that was fully functional and also adb.exe stop working. The strange thing is that adb.exe will not work any more even If I disconnect the phone and/or I connect my tablet. Adb.exe just got useless.

I was using the same phone yesterday (android 4.0), with my tablet (android 4.2) and adb.exe was working.

Adb.exe is not corrupted as I checked it MD5 and it is the same as in working pc (5787e5df1a68e7afea82d58e5f0d6549 *adb.exe).

I have Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.31 and Android SDK tools 22. I uninstalled android sdk tools and Installed again but when is near to finish it hangs because it launches adb.exe and again it will run forever.

Please any suggestion or help?

Comment: Did you check USB debugging in the phone ?

Comment: have you installed the phone driver? it is not the same of the usb driver. also, is the phone set to allow usb debugging?

Comment: Windows 7 automatically installs its own drivers for every single popular device.  Installing drivers manually will always lead to problems if its not needed.

Comment: @ZouZou he stated it worked on another computer. so yes.

Comment: @AdamOutler "I just connect the same phone to other PC that was fully functional and also adb.exe stop working"

Comment: Just to clarify, adb.exe is useless at all. Now it does not work with any phone/tablet. Even with no device connected is just run forever and no message... nothing.

Comment: please try disable antivirus and check again? uninstall drivers for phone and plug in again, maybe its driver problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try rebooting.  Sometimes the USB drivers lock up.  I work HEAVILY with ADB in my project at http://android-casual.googlecode.com and I find it to be one of three things when ADB locks up..  1. USB drivers, or 2. adb_usb.ini needs an update, or 3. on new devices you have to "pair" them so that ADB can perform any action.

To pair, you can disconnect, reconnect and run "adb devies" to display the pairing on the device.

Comment: I want to clarify that you should never install USB drviers unless the computer displays a red-x in device manager.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you're still facing this issue, but for what it's worth I had the same kind of issue with adb.exe, and came across this post while trying to troubleshoot it. In my case, I wasn't using any physical Android devices, only the Emulator. Everything had been working fine and then suddenly adb.exe would no longer respond (couldn't get any output from any adb command - it just appeared to hang).

In the end, my issue turned out to be another application I had installed on my development machine. It was starting as a service, and was listening on the exact same port that the adb server runs on (5037), which appeared to be confusing it. Once I changed the application to use a different port, adb started working again and everything was fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You saved my day. I first use `netstat -ano` to find out the pid which occupies port 5037. The pid doesn't appear in windows task manager. I then switch to sysinternal's TCPView, which kills the process nicely. After that adb starts normally. TCPView says it's svchost.exe occupying 5037, but I couldn't find out which service within svchost is it.

Answer (score 0):

Run command

`where adb`

I had such kind of situation.

In my case

`where adb`

gave output

`C:\Windows\adb.exe
D:\AndroidSDK\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe`

I tried to run adb from disk C, when Eclipse used second adb from AndroidSDK (from disk D).

I removed adb from strange path `C:\Windows\adb.exe`, and this solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem,my solution is going to cmd and paste adb.exe path,and then click enter button.
For example

```
D:\Android\Android\platform-tools\adb.exe
```