# adb.exe has stopped working, Nexus 7 not detected over USB

Tags: android, nexus-7, android-debug, google-nexus

I'm using Google Nexus 7 to debug an applications. but now it is prompting the error message below and and popup is coming stating that the USB device is not recognized.
But it was working properly a few days back.

I have not made any updates on the device or the Android SDK.

adb stopped:

[image]

USB device not recognized:

[image]

What's wrong?

Comment: If restarting the device and restarting the computer and using a different USB port (2.0, not HUB) doesn't work and you certainly do have USB Debugging set to ON, then there's a chance that the cable or the Nexus 7's port went haywire. I used to get this problem and I had to get the USB module of my Galaxy Note switched out because it corroded. That, of course, after messing quite a bit with the drivers that are quite problematic for Android on Windows 7 for some reason.

Comment: Try installing this driver http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-4/orig-development/adb-fb-apx-driver-universal-naked-t1996051 using `pnputil -i -a nameoffile.inf`

Comment: @ Zhuinden i tried all usb ports and on off stuff.. but not working

Comment: try on another computer, if it doesn't work on another computer then try with another cable, if with another cable it doesn't work on either computer then take the nexus 7 for its USB to be replaced, my Samsung Galaxy Note's USB was really fragile too (I had to get it replaced twice in three months O.o)

Comment: nop i tried also on many (five) computers buy using different usb cables. and still getting the same problem for those computers as well.

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44580544/5583806),i got the same problem,that is my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the adb executable,is executed several times causing this error, check on your Task Manager (not sure how it's named).

Kill all of them, and restart the adb by taping this command "adb devices" on any windows shell (cmd.exe or powershell).

Hope it'll help you :)

Comment: device manager is not showing  the device after the error popups, connected as a usb device. I tried to start the adb but device is not connected..

Comment: Is your nexus found  by Windows ? (on the File explorer or the Device Manager) If not, make sure your nexus is recognized by your system, you might need drivers (I had a problem with a Galaxy Tab 10.2 that forced me to unistall the Samsung USB Driver and reinstall it).

Comment: I found this, it is about nexus driver issue http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1821536

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me during debug, I just **unplugged and plugged back** the USB cable and adb return to work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

this question is about the adb server version in local machine doesn't match with the adb under the C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools;
find a same version of abd.exe copy to, then run, done well
i tried to find the key and resolve.